# Python 2.7: Concatenate, Trim, and Search text files

Tags: python

I have multiple text files that contain a stream of text data.  There are headers that break up the data based on a count.  The issue is the header for a the chunk of data I'm interested in could be in another file.  It looks like this...

file1.txt

```
=======Boot Count 1============
(random text strings)
...
...
...
=======Boot Count 2============
...
```

file2.txt

```
...
...
...
=======Boot Count 3============
...
...
=======Boot Count 4============
...
```

file3.txt

```
...
...
```

I need to find some information that is located in the latest boot count.  So I need to

1. Concatenate the text files together
2. Search backwards until I see a boot count header
3. Trim all of the extra stuff out
4. Then only search that last part for a particular string.

I can handle #4.  Any ideas on 1-3?

Comment: so basically you want the highest boot count section?

Comment: Correct. After that I can use a regex to find what I'm looking for, but first I need the right section to search through

Comment: Why not just search through each file one by one looking for boot counts, and just save the most recent? That would eliminate (1) and make (2) easier.

Comment: Because a file is not guaranteed to have a boot count in it.  The header could be in one file and the content can roll over into another

Comment: @njfrazie, why do you need to concatenate the files,surely all you want is the latest boot count and to search from there down?

Comment: Since the multiple files are really one big stream of data, plus the fact the header can be in a different file, I thought concatenating all of the files, searching backwards until I hit the header, then starting forward again would be the way to go

Comment: The reasons you're giving for not being able to do this in the normal, straightforward manner are invalid. Can you please give the normal way a try?

Answer (score 1):

Just check each file and find the one with the latest count:

```
from itertools import islice
with open("file1.txt") as f1, open("file2.txt") as f2, open("file3.txt") as f3:
    best_count,index,f_obj = 0,0,None
    import re
    r = re.compile("Boot\s+Count\s+(\d+)")      
    for obj in (f1, f2, f3):
        for ind, line in enumerate(obj,1):
            match = r.search(line)
            if match:
                i = int(match.group())
                if i > best_count:
                    best_count = i
                    index = ind
                    f_obj = obj
    f_obj.seek(0)
    for line in islice(f_obj, index):# search for the string
        print(line)
```

`best_count`,`index` and `f_obj` will keep track of the line of where the latest count is and which file it is in, you can then just seek back to the start and use itertools.islice to get the section you want from the file with the latest count.

You could also use `if line[0] == "="` to maybe speed up the search if the only lines with the count always start with a `=`.

Comment: I like this however the header and the data aren't guaranteed to be together.  So if the highest boot count is in file2, the actual data I want to find could be in file3.

Comment: Then you can still use the same logic, once you find the file, if you don't hit another boot count in that section then start reading the next file until you do and that will be all the section, if you do hit a boot count it should be all in the one file. If you prefer then read all the files as one long file

Comment: How would I redo the with statement if I have an unknown number of files?  I've been looking at the fileinput module to do this but it's missing some things

Comment: `for file in iterable_of_filename:with open(file) as f:...`

Answer (score 0):

I found a method to accomplish what I need.  It's similar to Padraic's approach.

```
def issue(path):
    #path is full path with a wild card character:
    #example: "C:\users\joeShmoe\file*"         

    count = 0
    linenumber = 0
    fileList = []
    fileindex = 1
    bootFound = False

    for name in sorted(glob.glob(path)):
        fileList.append(name)

    for file in fileList:
        if bootFound == True:
            break

        fileindex += 1

        for line in reversed(open(file,'rb').readlines()):
            content = line.rstrip()
            b = re.compile(ur'(BOOT COUNT =)')
            bootCount = re.search(b,content)
            linenumber += 1
            if (bootCount is not None) :
                bootFound = True
                break

    if bootFound == False:
        return None

    filesearch = sorted(fileList[:fileindex],reverse=True)
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fileinput.input(files=filesearch)]

    startpt = len(lines) - linenumber

    if len(lines)  <= 0:
        return None

    if startpt <= 0:
        startpt = 0

    for line in islice(lines,startpt,len(lines)):
            content = line.rstrip()
            p = re.compile(ur'FAILURE HERE')
            failure = re.search(p,content)
            if (failure is not None):
                return 1

    return None
```